# What's an alternative to throwing an exception when managing pattern matching with guards?

Tags: f#

What's an alternative to throwing an exception when managing pattern matching with guards?

```
[<Literal>]
let Objective = 33

let (|NotGame|IsGame|) p =
    match p with
    | LessThanGame v when v <  Objective -> NotGame v
    | Game         v when v >= Objective -> IsGame  v
```

**Warning:**

> Incomplete pattern matches on this expression

I don't want any complaints from the compiler.

**As a result, what I don't want to do is this:**

```
let (|NotGame|IsGame|) p =
    match p with
    | LessThanGame v when v <  Objective -> NotGame v
    | Game         v when v >= Objective -> IsGame  v
    | _ -> failwith "idk..."
```

**What I would rather do is this:**

```
let (|NotGame|IsGame|) p =
    match p with
    | LessThanGame v when v <  Objective -> NotGame v
    | Game         v when v >= Objective -> IsGame  v
    | _ v                                -> IsGame  v
```

**The entire code is here:**

```
// ***********
// Game of 33 
// ************************************************************
(*Types*)
// ************************************************************
type Player = 
    | Player1
    | Player2

type Shot = 
     | TwoPointer
     | ThreePointer
     | FoulShot
     | TwoFoulShots
     | ThreeFoulShots

type PlayerScore = {Player:Player; Points:Points}

and Points = 
    | LessThanGame of int
    | Game of int

type Posession = Posession of Player

[<Literal>]
let Objective = 33

// ************************************************************
(*Active Patterns*)
// ************************************************************
let (|NotGame|IsGame|) = function
    | LessThanGame v when v <  Objective -> NotGame v
    | Game         v when v >= Objective -> IsGame  v
    | _ -> failwith "idk..."

// ************************************************************
(*Functions*)
// ************************************************************
let makeShot shot (shooter, defender) =

    let ballHandler = shooter.Player
    let points = shooter.Points

    let shotValue = match shot with
                    | TwoPointer   | TwoFoulShots   -> 2
                    | ThreePointer | ThreeFoulShots -> 3
                    | FoulShot                      -> 1

    match points with 
    | NotGame p ->  if p + shotValue < Objective then
                         { Player=ballHandler; Points=LessThanGame (p + shotValue) }, defender
                    else { Player=ballHandler; Points=Game         (p + shotValue) }, defender

    | IsGame  p -> { Player=ballHandler; Points=Game p }, defender

let startGame = 

    let player1Score = { Player=Player1; Points=LessThanGame 0 }
    let player2Score = { Player=Player2; Points=LessThanGame 0 }

    (player1Score, player2Score)

// ************************************************************
(*Client*)
// ************************************************************
let player1Score, player2Score = startGame

let player1, player2 = (player1Score, player2Score) |> makeShot TwoPointer
let shooter, defender = player2, player1

let final = (shooter, defender) |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot FoulShot

                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot TwoFoulShots

                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot ThreeFoulShots

                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
```

**Resolution:**

As Guy Coder advised, I use if/else conditions as an alternative. Thus, this removed the need for me to throw an exception.

```
// ************************************************************
(*Types*)
// ************************************************************
type Player = | Player1 | Player2

type Shot = 
     | TwoPointer| ThreePointer
     | FoulShot  | TwoFoulShots | ThreeFoulShots

type PlayerScore = {Player:Player; Game:Game}

and Game = 
    | Underway of int
    | AlmostGame of int
    | GameTime of int

[<Literal>]
let Objective = 33

[<Literal>]
let MaxFoulShots = 3

let (|Underway|AlmostGame|Game|) (score,shot) =

    let shotValue = match shot with
                    | FoulShot                      -> 1
                    | TwoPointer   | TwoFoulShots   -> 2
                    | ThreePointer | ThreeFoulShots -> 3

    match score, shotValue with
    | Underway   s,v -> if (s + v) <= (Objective - MaxFoulShots)
                        then Underway   (s + v)
                        else AlmostGame (s + v)

    | AlmostGame s,v -> if ( (s+v) < Objective )
                        then AlmostGame (s + v)
                        else Game Objective

    | GameTime   s,v -> Game s

// ************************************************************
(*Functions*)
// ************************************************************
let makeShot shot (shooter, defender) =

    match (shooter.Game, shot) with
    | Underway p   -> { shooter with Game=Underway p }, defender
    | AlmostGame p -> { shooter with Game=AlmostGame p }, defender
    | Game p       -> { shooter with Game=GameTime p }, defender

let startGame = 

    let player1Score = { Player=Player1; Game=Underway 0 }
    let player2Score = { Player=Player2; Game=Underway 0 }

    (player1Score, player2Score)

// ************************************************************
(*Client*)
// ************************************************************
let player1Score, player2Score = startGame

let player1, player2 = (player1Score, player2Score) |> makeShot TwoPointer
let shooter, defender = player2, player1

let final = (shooter, defender) |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot FoulShot

                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot TwoFoulShots

                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot ThreeFoulShots

                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot ThreePointer
                                |> makeShot ThreePointer

                                |> makeShot FoulShot
                                |> makeShot FoulShot
                                |> makeShot ThreeFoulShots
```

Comment: As soon as you have a when the compiler stops checking and issues a warning unless you have a wildcard.  Can't really be fixed and I think there was a dupe yesterday

Comment: John, the difference is that I have a value attached to a union case. Yesterday's question did not have attached data. Instead the value was just an int and not a union case.

Comment: Oh the _ v thing can't be done either. Still a duplicate

Comment: scott wlaschin advised not to throw exceptions when you own the code being executed. Thus, this code is not performing I/O. Any suggestions?

Comment: How would you like to handle the case where the input is `LessThanGame` when the contained value is greater than or equal to the objective? How would you like to handle the case where the input is `Game` when the contained value is less than the objective?

Comment: I believe I handled it in the "makeShot" function in which I analyze the current points and then update the state of the points with the appropriate union case. In addition, I really do want to "make illegal states unrepresentable". However, I wasn't sure what else I could do in regards to using the type system.

Comment: I could create types zero thru thirtyFive. That would guarantee that unrepresentable can't be created. However, where does one draw the line in regards to the amount of effort to do this?

Comment: Can you give the reference from which you quote Scott Wlaschin?

Comment: He discusses it in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8I19uA-wGY. In the video, he advises not to throw an exception when dividing by zero. Instead, he advises to create a type called Nonzero.

Comment: I was asking to see the context in which he made the statement. You clarified it in the comment. I didn't think he would ever make such a blanket statement. On a side note I am starting to think the cliché about dividing by zero is just that a cliché because it depends upon the context in which you divide by zero. If you start with a logical foundation then dividing by zero results in false; it is not an exception or any contrived way to get around it as if it wore a problem. Hopefully you see where I am going with this, its the context that matters and you are the one defining the context.

Comment: Yes. I think I understand. However, I am fighting the compiler on fuzzy logic and as a result am having to write cruft just to satisfy the compiler instead of the domain challenge.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly you are trying to classify the input into just two buckets and the conditional is `less than`. If so then forgo the pattern matching and just use an `if` statement. There is no rule that says to be functional one must use a pattern matching for all decisions. The other way I see it is that you are trying to do input validation at the same time as classification. Let the input validation handle the problems and the classification will not have these outlier cases.

Comment: @GuyCoder - You can post your latest comment as the answer and I will award you credit. I have posted my resolution code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you are trying to classify the input into just two buckets and the conditional is `less than`.

If so then forgo the pattern matching and just use an `if` statement. There is no rule that says to be functional one must use a pattern matching for all decisions.